# MVP multiples views combine to form an overall view

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

The `GWT` documentation comes with a tutorial on how to utilize the `MVP` pattern [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture). In this example, there are two views, and each replace the other as per the user action.

In these rather simple views, it didn't hurt much to cram all widgets that `view` has in one single class (`view`) only. But for a complex `view`, one would like to create individual `view`s for components (with a corresponding `presenter` for each such component `view`), then combine those `view`s into the overall `view`s (this combined `view` may or may not have a separate combined `presenter`, since all sub-views already have corresponding `presenters`). Somewhat similar to creating individual widgets in separate classes that extend `Composite`, calling `initWidget` on them, and using them like `mainPanel.add(new subPanel())` in the main panel.

So is it possible to do such thing in `MVP` pattern in `GWT`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean, the documentation is pretty sparse, so a working example would be great...

Comment: Sorry to give you hope and pull it away. I know it can be done. I did it a couple of years ago at another employer. I don't have access to the code to go see how I did it and I don't remember the details. Here's a bit more. The init on the whole screen calls init on each of the sub-screens. I think I had a master presenter that pulled details together and gave unified access to the bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you do so the entire `DOM` load in a single shot,even though you put `if else` conditions inside .

When building large applications with `GWT`,Using MVP and  code splitting is a must – otherwise,
the entire application (i.e. JavaScript bundle) is downloaded in one chunk on the initial 
load of the application, which is a good recipe for frustrated users!

By using standard MVP you can

```
Isolate of User Interface from Business tier

Easily interchangeable Views (user interfaces)

Ability to test all code more effectively
```

I suppose you are expecting like below

```
public class MainPageView extends ViewImpl implements MainPagePresenter.MyView {


    @UiField
    public HTMLPanel mainMenuPanel;

    @UiField
    public HTMLPanel mainContentPanel;

    @UiField
    public HTMLPanel mainFooterPanel;

.
.
.
.
.etc
```

Yes instead of panels as shown above , you can also use classes which have some elements inside.

Update:

To `mainMenuPanel`  you can add your class like mainMenuPanel.add(new MyheaderClass()).
Where `MyheaderClass` extends of `Panel` or `Widget` .So that the all elements in the Class add to the  `mainMenuPanel`

Inside your `MyheaderClass` class you may add `labels`, `buttons` ...etc by using `this.add(mybutton)`..etc

Comment: I didn't exactly get you. Imagine my project is currently not MVP-compliant, but I want to make it so. It is structured into three panels, top, center and bottom, which are called in the main module. Those three panels are defined in separate classes (I invoke it by calling `initWidget`). Those classes themselves contain multiple other widgets which also are defined in separate classes, and these cascading goes on for quite a few levels. So in place of panels or widgets being defined in individual classes, can i replace them views and another corresponding presenter class?

Comment: Yes you can use without any hesitations .

Comment: Can you give me an idea how?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. I have been doing the same with widgets. Declare the widgets in individual classes and call `initWidget` on them, and add them in the parent panel like `parentPanel.add(new subPanel())`. That `parentpanel` itself may be a subpanel, so after calling `initWidget` on that too, it can be added to its parent panel like `headPanel.add(new parentPanel())`. But now we have views in place of panels. Those panels contained the events in the same class, here the views contain only the widgets, with the events being outsourced to its presenter. How to add now?

Comment: I mean, something like this. There is a view named `subView1' which is tied to presenter `subViewPresenter1`. Similarly for `subView2` and `subView3`. I now want to add these three to say a parent view `nestedViews`. This view is just a container, it need not have a presenter additionally, since all subviews have presenters to take care of their events. How do I now add those three sub views to this parent view?

Comment: Seems like you are talking about nested presenters  check this link   http://uptick.com.au/content/serendipity-working-gwt-platform-and-smartgwt

Comment: In above link  check the implementation of MainPageSmartGwtView 
class  and  in methods setInSlot and  initApplicationMenu() In that they are  adding 3 presenters inside main presenter.Hope that will clear your doubts .

Comment: Check this nice example .http://www.rubiconred.com/blog/using-gwt-mvp-with-multiple-views-on-the-page/

Comment: Ummm, the first example you pointed out is cool, but I am feeling a tad lost. It's a pretty big example...

Comment: By the way, that example is based on `SmartGWT`. A detailed example is given at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted, but that uses `GWTP`. Is it not possible to do it in plain `GWT`?

Comment: Its possible .  No worries :)

Comment: Can you give me an example (a spoon-feeding kind) ? :D

Comment: :D  you did'nt get any example there? In the above links which i given.

Comment: They are in `SmartGWT` flavor...:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24394/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-cupidvogel)